# Send allows access to private variables

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, access-specifier

Consider the following code:

```
def create_class(class_name, superclass, &block)
    klass = Class.new superclass, &block
    Object.const_set class_name, klass
end
```

After I do:

```
create_class('User', ActiveRecord::Base)
```

the following is ok:

```
Object.send(:remove_const, :User)
```

but this:

```
Object.remove_const :User
```

results in this:

```
NoMethodError: private method `remove_const' called for Object:Class
```

? Does not make sense for me... can 'send' override Ruby's access checks? Please help!

Comment: There's not really such a thing as a private variable in Ruby. They're all private. Only methods have access control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it does override Ruby's access checks.

http://joshstaiger.org/archives/2006/12/the_ruby_send_h.html

My guess is that you would like to play nicely with things other people have made private. If you need to use send to call methods of a class you did not create, you should probably call [obj.respond_to](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000332) on it first.

Comment: looks like it... thanks! by the way, do you how can 'remove_const' be _sanely_ called, i.e., which other method calls it?

Comment: A quick google search reveals this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Reflection/Callremoveconsttoremoveaclassdefinition.htm

I haven't tried it, so it could be wrong. Also, you may want to change the title of your question to something like "send allows access to private variables" so that it can be more easily searched for.